# Scripts for moving schema changes from development database to production database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to head this one off at the pass. I've got two database servers (DEV and PRD) and I have my database on the DEV server. I am looking to deploy v1 of my application to PRD server.

The question is this: Say in two months, I am ready to ship v1.1 of my application, which introduces two new VIEWS, six new fields (three fields in two tables, each), and an updated version of my sproc that creates records in the tables with new fields. My DEV database has the new schema, but my PRD database has the real data, so I can't simply copy the .mdf file, since I want to keep my PRD data, but include my new schema.

I understand doing the initial creation of tables, views, sprocs via saved .sql files; but what I'm wondering is, is it possible to use SSMS to create the appripriate "alter table" scripts or do I need to manually do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have handled this with a release update SQL script that applies the changes to the previous version.

You either need to code this yourself or use one of the many DBA tools to do database compares and generate a diff script.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that will do this for you [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) is one of them and one I like the best

Otherwise you have to code these yourself and don't forget to also script the permissions if you recreate the proc (unless you use ALTER PROC in that case permissions are preserved)

Comment: What is a tool like that called? I'd like to find an open-source one if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since your database changes should be in scripts that are under source control, you just load them with the version that you are moving to prod just like any other code associated with that version. One you you never under any circumstances do is make changes to the dev (or any other) datbase, using the User interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try the patching engine found in DBSourceTools.
http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com
DBSourceTools is a utility to help developers get their databases under source control.
Simply point it at a Source Database, and it will script all database objects, incuding data to disk.
Once you have a Target database (v1), you can then place your patch scripts int the patches directory, and DBSourceTools will run these patches in order after re-creating your database.
This is a very effective means of thoroughly testing your change scripts.